How could I modify document{report} fontsize?
I tried
\documentclass[20pt]{report}

however it doesn't work.
I need to resize the whole document fontsize.

You can use fontsize (but you need a freely scalable font).
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lmodern} % or other scalable font
\usepackage[fontsize=20pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixcmex}% if you use lmodern

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Font used: \fontname\font

\lipsum

\end{document}



You want to use the exsizes package/classes. This allows you to use 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt and 20pt as class options.
For your example:
\documentclass[20pt]{extreport}

